# How do I inject declarative service into my spring bean

Tags: spring, service, dependency-injection, declarative-services, bnd

I have a third party lib which is exposing declarative service. But I have a spring bean class.

How do I inject this declarative service into my spring bean class?

Answer (score 0):

You must declare this service also as a bean so it can be managed by spring.